# Algebraic expression

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us put

$$c = (a + b)/2$$

Is it possible to express

$$d  = ab = f(c)$$

as the function of c?

We can write

$$ab = (a + b)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 +ab)$$
$$2ab = (a+b)^2 - (a^2 + b^2)= 4c^2 -(a^2 + b^2)$$

How to continue with the second member?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, because $ab$ can take many different values that result in the same value for $\frac{a+b}{2}$.

For example, if $c=4$, we could have $a=b=4, ab=16$, or $a=2,b=6,ab=12$, or $a=1,b=7, ab=7$, etc.

Indeed, by the [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) inequality, we know that $c^2\ge d$. And that's all we know - it's possible to choose $a$ and $b$ that result in any such $c,d$.

edit - that inequality doesn't properly take into account negative values of $ab$, but you get the general idea.